# send a SOAP request using php curl

Tags: php, curl, soap

I'm having this code which i want to use it to send a SOAP request but the result is nothing at all no success nor error codes or messages. So how can I send a correct SOAP request to the correct url using the following code

```
Service Endpoint URL
https://pod.test.at.serviceDomain.com

Web Service Definition Language (WSDL) URL
https://pod.test.at.serviceDomain.com/pod/services/PodService?wsdl

$soapUrl = "https://pod.test.at.serviceDomain.com/pod/services/PodService?wsdl"; // I've tried the other url but the same result
$soapUser = "testuser";  //  username
$soapPassword = "testpass"; // password

$xml_post_string = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wsdl:definitions name='PodService' targetNamespace='http://www.serviceDomain.com/enterprise/distribution/podService/v1' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/'
      xmlns:tns='http://www.serviceDomain.com/enterprise/distribution/podService/v1' 
  xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
<wsdl:documentation>Version: 1.0.0</wsdl:documentation>
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace='http://www.serviceDomain.com/enterprise/distribution/podService/v1'
                  xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' 
                  xmlns:tns='http://www.serviceDomain.com/enterprise/distribution/podService/v1' 
                  xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/' 
                  xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
        <xsd:element name='executeOrder'>
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name='username' type='testuser'>
                        </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name='password' type='testpass'>
                        </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs='0' name='retailerId' type='tns:'>
                        </xsd:element>                       
                    <xsd:element name='orderId' type='tns:123456'>
                        </xsd:element>                        
                    <xsd:element name='faceValue' type='tns:50.00'>
                        </xsd:element>                        
                    <xsd:element name='productId' type='tns:000666'>
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>";

       $headers = array(
            "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
            "Accept: text/xml",
            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
            "Pragma: no-cache",
            "SOAPAction: \"run\"",
            "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
        );

        $url = $soapUrl;

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlRequest);
        [update: changed to:] 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        echo $response;


        $response1 = str_replace("<soap:Body>","",$response);
        $response2 = str_replace("</soap:Body>","",$response1);

        $parser = simplexml_load_string($response2);
        echo $parser['resultCode'];

       curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: your request contained in `$xml_post_string` but in your `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` you put `$xmlRequest`

Comment: changed curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlRequest); to curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); and still getting a blank page

Comment: You are sending XML schema to the URL and not the XML data. I think you need to pass XML data instead if the XSD data. Please check again whether you are passing correct data or not.

Comment: removed all the schema and kept just xml data and still getting nothing at all

Comment: like @JugalK said, you have to send xml request data. You should try to use tools like soap ui to fetch request structure from all request functions in wsdl.

Comment: @PHPUser What is your XML data exactly..??? The data you are trying to pass here is entirely the Schema data. You need to pass the xml data which will look something like:
 
<executeOrder>

<username>abc</username> .

...

</executeOrder>

Comment: I've tried using SoapUI 5.2 but I get this error "Error loading [https://pod.test.at.servicewebsitehere.com/pod/services/PodService?wsdl]: java.lang.Exception: Failed to load url; https://pod.test.at.servicewebsitehere.com/pod/services/PodService?wsdl, 0 -"

Comment: @PHPUser because there is no URL present like that. The URL seems to be incorrect. Please recheck whether it's  the exact URL where you want's to send the data.